# Firebase database no class found error (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have large project that uses multiple sub-modules, I have added the firebase database dependency to one of my modules that is included in my project. When testing locally where modules are included as open projects everything works fine, when building using closed modules (my modules come as `aar` files) I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase;

I have include the following dependency in my module:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

I have tried adding to proguard the following rule but it's not helping:

```
-keep public class com.google.firebase.database.** {
    *;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After doing a lot of research, I think this issue is related to having `multiDex` enabled.

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase" on path: DexPathList
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the world of the bullshit errors of Firebase. You have to find somewhere where you're retrieving data from the database but providing the incorrect class afaik]

Comment: show the gradle file

Comment: Actually, welcome to the world of programming

Comment: Maybe add the gradle file, so someone can check? Or don't its alright

Comment: @PeterHaddad the gradle file of the app or module?

Comment: the app gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by checking the `POM` file of my library. I noticed that the firebase database dependency was missing from the `POM` file even though i have added it to my `build.gradle`, which means something went wrong with the publish to bintray gradle task!

I made a fix to the gradle task and now all good.