# Firebase not working at all with no error messages

Tags: android, firebase

I had NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbgl implementing Firebase authentication

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237242/11106497) answer and now no activities using firebase is showing up and no error messages

app.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is an error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842677/firebase-database-no-class-found-error-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: You did not implement `firebase-core` using `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'`. Does it work after adding it?